# How to force express to always serve a fresh index.html?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

So I have a create-react-app bootstrapped application that is being served by express. I've noticed that for some of my users their browser is caching the index.html and as a result my application is making requests for non-existent js and css assets.

To prevent this from happening, I've tried setting the cache control header on the express static server to be "no-cache"..which did not work. I've also tried forcing the ETAG to be false so the browser is forced to take back a new index.html, but this hasn't worked either.

This is how I am serving my application

```
app.get('/*', forceHttps)

// root (/) should always serve our server rendered page
// other static resources should be served as they are
const root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')
app.use(
  express.static(root, {
    maxAge: '1d',
    etag: false,
    setHeaders: (res, requestedFilePath) => {
      if (requestedFilePath.endsWith('.html')) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
      }
    },
  })
)
app.get('/*', function(request, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```

1. Why do I run into this issue at all? After every build `index.html` changes and the ETAG should change because the `index.html` is different.
2. Why isn't my current solution working? I'm forcing there to be no cache

   3. How do I solve this problem? I have existing users that have a stale index.html and I need to cache bust.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you serving direct or through a reverse proxy (cloudflare, cloudfront...)?

Comment: It's sitting on a 3 node EKS cluster, but ELB doesn't cach.